# Meteor, fabricjs canvas on multiple templates causes memory leak

Tags: meteor, memory-leaks, fabricjs

I have a simple meteor app with two templates using flowrouter to navigate between them. Each template has a single HTML canvas element in it both have a fabricjs canvas assigned and a box drawn.

When I navigate between the two templates while doing a memory performance profile I see the memory continuously increase at every navigation between templates.

I expected the garbage collector to clean up the canvas vars but its not. So something keeping them in context.   I can't see what I'm missing here.

Template HTML

```
<template name="one">
        Template One 
        <a href="/two"> two</a>
        <div>
                <canvas id="canvasONE" width="2000" height="1601"></canvas>
        </div>
</template>

<template name="two">
    Template Two
    <a href="/one"> one</a>
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvasTWO" width="2000" height="1601"></canvas>
    </div>
</template>
```

// JavaScript

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';


import './main.html';
//////////////////////////////////////////////   
// Template One  


Template.one.onRendered( function(){
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvasONE',{selection:true});

  var rec = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: 120,
    height: 50,
    rx: 4,
    ry: 4,
    fill: '#64b5f6',
    stroke: '#6Ebfff',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top',
    lockScalingX: true,
    lockScalingY: true 

});

canvas.add(rec)

})


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Template Two

Template.two.onRendered( function(){
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvasTWO',{selection:true});

    var rec = new fabric.Rect({
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      width: 120,
      height: 50,
      rx: 4,
      ry: 4,
      fill: '#223344',
      stroke: '#6Ebfff',
      strokeWidth: 2,
      originX: 'left',
      originY: 'top',
      lockScalingX: true,
      lockScalingY: true

      });

      canvas.add(rec)
  })
```

Thanks...

UPDATE: after a few hours debugging, it appears to be DOM related. The meteor template removes the DOM elements but fabric could still be referencing it. The GC leaves it in memory.  I added an extra function to each template to try clear the fabric canvas.

```
Template.one.onDestroyed( function(){
  rec = null;
  canvas.clear();
  canvas.dispose();
  $(canvas.wrapperEl).remove()
})
```

but still seeing the memory leak continue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved.

I moved the var canvas definition outside of the function blocks to the root of the file, In meteor this makes it global to the scope of the file, not a true application global. The fabricjs canvas clear() dispose() were from a recommendation by one of the authors of fabric posted as an answer to someone else's question,